# Cloud Code Functions will not work after Parse Server migration to Heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I followed the migration path from the parse website to Heroku.

Parse initializes but I cannot find any of my cloud code functions from my JS Angular Web App, example :-

```
Parse.Cloud.run('checkStats',{'id' : id }
```

The network tab shows POST request with a 404.

```
http://..../parse/1/functions/checkStats
```

As I test I used hurl.it (http tool) and got the same results, I then changed the url and removed the /1/ and the function works.

```
http://..../parse/functions/checkStats
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to update my Parse JS SDK to the latest version (1.6.14) on the client side. In addition, on the cloud code side, code changes were required as Parse.User.current() or Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()  are no longer supported, instead you need to use different functions for the same result... refer to
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server